# IE goes blank when it the activex is downloading for the first time

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I am using an activex control in one of my web pages. The size of the activex is 3MB+.
For the first time, when the user comes to the page, user gets a blank screen till the activex is downloading and the screen does not load until the activex is completely downloaded.

Is there a way to show some kind of a message to the user till the actual screen gets loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check sample [here](http://demo.aurigma.com/ImageUploader6/BasicDemo/default.aspx), maybe it will be helpful...

Comment: Thanks will look into this. So the idea is not to load the activex on along with the page. Inject the markup for the activex programmatically through js?

Comment: The idea of the sample – yes. But usually ActiveX installation begins after rendering all other page content, regardless of injection method – JavaScript or object tag. I suppose the cause in your page and the sample I gave you will help you to find the reason.